# data not saving in textbox properties.settings

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, save

I am working on a project where I want to save the text that is in the textbox when im closing the application, and when I open the application again I want it to be there.

I am trying to save the text data in the app.config as you can see in the code below but when I close the application and run it, the text I put in is not there.

Im really confused because when the form loads it runs this

> textbox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SavedText;

and it should pull up the "saved text" which is being saved when the form is calling the Closing event

> Properties.Settings.Default.SavedText = textbox1.Text;
>   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework;
using MetroFramework.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textbox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SavedText;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.SavedText = textbox1.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

I was also getting these errors before and I tried showing the potential fixes and use them but they didnt solve the issue with the text not saving.
[image]

This were the potential fixes.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by going into my project properties and adding this to the project settings. SavedText > String > User.